# Count all rows from a column, and get 2 different count columns on the result even if there are not records to count

Tags: sql-server

What I want to do is to count all rows from a column `State`, and get 2 different count columns on the result (one for each possible value 1 or 0).

The thing is that I need to show on the results 0 even if there are not records to count.

For example I have this table `subcategory` with this sample data:

```
  SubcategoryID |   Name    |
  ---------------------------
        201     |   Name1   |
        202     |   Name2   |
        203     |   Name3   |
        204     |   Name4   |
```

And I have this table `product` with this sample data:

```
  ProductID |Subcategory| State |
  -------------------------------
    101     |   201     |   1   |
    102     |   201     |   1   |
    103     |   201     |   1   |
    104     |   202     |   0   |
    105     |   202     |   0   |
    106     |   203     |   1   |
    107     |   203     |   0   |
    108     |   203     |   0   |
```

State: 1 = Active, 0 = Inactive

So I want to get this:

```
|Subcategory| Active|Inactive|
------------------------------
|   201     |   3   |   0    |
|   202     |   0   |   2    |
|   203     |   1   |   2    |
|   204     |   0   |   0    |*
```

Please note that there are not products related to SubcategoryId = 204 on product table.

I'm using this query to get only the products that are related to one subcategory. Do you know what I have to add to get the line  "|204|0|0|" ?

```
select p.subcategory,
       sum(case when state = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as active,
       sum(case when state = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as inactive
from product p
group by p.subcategory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Left Join` to get all the rows from `subcategory` table and then do the `Count`.

```
SELECT S.subcategoryID,
       Sum(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active,
       Sum(CASE WHEN state = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inactive
FROM   subcategory s
       LEFT JOIN product p
              ON s.SubcategoryID = p.Subcategory
GROUP  BY s.subcategoryID
```

Or use `Count`, case statement `else` part can be avoided

```
SELECT S.subcategoryID,
       count(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 1 END) AS active,
       count(CASE WHEN state = 0 THEN 1 END) AS inactive
FROM   subcategory s
       LEFT JOIN product p
              ON s.SubcategoryID = p.Subcategory
GROUP  BY s.subcategoryID
```

### [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c350/3)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it.

```
--Getting the counts for 'active' and 'inactive' states
SELECT S.subcategoryID,
       count(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 1 END) AS active,
       count(CASE WHEN state = 0 THEN 1 END) AS inactive
FROM   subcategory s
       JOIN product P ON s.SubcategoryID = p.Subcategory
GROUP  BY s.subcategoryID 

--Now adding subcategories which are only in subcategory table using `EXCEPT`.
UNION ALL
(
SELECT subcategoryid, 0, 0 from subcategory
EXCEPT
SELECT subcategory, 0, 0 from product
)
```